# Selenium Python - RecursionError('maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison')

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, recursionerror

when executing the Selenium Python script, the following terrible error appears:

```
object address: 000001340
object refcount: 2
object type: 00007FFA03482550
object type name: RecursionError
object repr: Recursion Error('maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison')
lost sys.stderr

Process ended with exit code 1.
```

How can I fix this?
Perhaps the following information will be useful:

- Driver: Chrome 117
- The code after which, most likely, an error occurred:

```
try:
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.styles_radioButton__l8XWY:nth-child(2)')))
except:
    pass
else:
    el.click()
```

When I encountered this error for the first time, I started Googling, but I didn't find anything about Selenium.